# How to properly release a Singleton View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, singleton

My application is music player app, where I have a singleton VC called `nowplayingVC`.

First let me explain why the singleton VC approach, well basically in my `nowplayingVC` I have album arts etc that are queried from network, and I dont want this to happen everytime which it will if I constantly pop/push `nowplayingVC`.

This is how I am able to acheive the singleton:

```
class NowPlayingController: UIViewController{
   static let sharedInstance: NowPlayingController = {
        let instance: NowPlayingController = UIStoryboard(name: "Music", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "music") as! NowPlayingController
        return instance
    }()
}
```

So each time I want push this `nowplayingVC`, I just go,

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(NowPlayingController.sharedInstance, animated: true)
```

But here is where I am stuck, I profiled this `nowplayingVC`, and its reference count is 1, caused by the static sharedInstance variable. I am also using timers inside the `nowplayingVC`, which means deinit() must be called, which is where I invalidate() timer.

> At what point can I remove this `nowplayingVC`, from memory will be
>   somewhere inside AppDelegate maybe inside applicationWillTerminate{} ?
>   or will it automatically call deinit()? also how can I bring it back
>   to 0?

I just want to know what is the best approach for this scenario is, Thanks

Comment: Honestly a view controller probably shouldn't be a singleton at all

Comment: Singletons can't be released; that is the point of the singleton pattern.  There will always only be one instance and the lifetime of that instance is the lifetime of your app.  When the app terminates all memory is released.  Your view controller should not be a singleton; some data model object should be.  The view controller can reference the album art etc from the data model.

Comment: @Paulw11interesting then that might be the only solution to my problem, to use a data model. Thanks!